# C# .NET でMySQLデータベースへの接続エラー；System.Net.Sockets.SocketException 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

初めてVisualStudio2017, C# .NET Frameworkを使用します。
一度似たような内容で質問しているのですが、
別のエラーがでてしまい、いろいろ自分で調べやってみたのですが、
解決できなかったので今回もアドバイス頂ければ幸いです。
C#.NETでMySQL Connector/Netを用いてデータベースに接続し、
テーブル内のデータを表示させてたいと考えています。
他の方のやり方を参考にやってみているのですが、
サーバーとの接続にエラーがでてしまい困っております。
まず、ローカルサーバーの場合Hostはlocalhostであっています？
念のためIPアドレスでも試してみたのですが、
そちらでもサーバーへのアクセス出来ないとエラーが出てしまいまいました。
同じ様なエラーが出た方を参考に、
開発側のPCのウイルスソフトを切り、
サーバーのfirewallも切りました。

環境
アプリケーション開発:windows,visual studio 2017, C# .net frameworkを使用 
サーバー:上記のwindows上でVirtualBox,vegrantを用いたローカールサーバー(CentOS)を立ち上げMySQLをインストール
仮想サーバーの立ち上げ流れ:
 1. VirtualBox, Vagrantをインストール
 2. Windows PowerShellを用いてVagrantを起動
 ※その際の振り当てたIPアドレスでもC#.NETへの接続を試しましたがエラーが出てしまいました。
 3. Puttyで仮想サーバーにアクセス
 4. MySQLをインストール
 5. 作業ユーザー、テーブルを制作

ここまで行ったこと：
基本的に以下のサイトをトレースしました。
http://web.sfc.wide.ad.jp/~tinaba/tutorials/mysql-net/
MySQL Connector/NetはPCに落としただけで
セットアップなどはとくになにも行っておりません。
（他にセットアップが必要な場合は教えて頂けると幸いです。）
VSでFormプロジェクトを作成しMySQL.Dataを参照から追加し、
ボタンの動作を以下で定義しました。

コード:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //サーバー接続
            string connstr = "userid=***; password=***; database=***; Host=localhost";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
            conn.Open();

            // データを格納するテーブル作成
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // SQL文と接続情報を指定し、データアダプタを作成
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from test1", conn);

            // データ取得
            da.Fill(dt);

            // データ表示
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            // 接続の解除
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error;

> SocketException: 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: 「環境」の記載がよくわからないのですが、・作成した.NETアプリはWindows側で動く、・MySQLサーバは(仮想環境の)CentOS側にインストールした、と言う事なのでしょうか? Windows側のアプリで`localhost`を指定する場合は、MySQLサーバもWindows側で動いていないといけません。「対象のコンピューターによって拒否」の原因は他にも考えられますが、まずは環境をもう少し詳しくご説明ください。

Comment: ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。お察し頂いた通りです。説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: ご質問の編集ありがとうございます。ただ期待したような情報は追加された中に入っていないようです。特に、リンク先記事のMySQL環境構築の部分はWindows側にMySQLを入れるように書かれているので、あなたがどのようにVagrant環境を設定・構築したのかが全くわかりません。・Vagrantで構成した仮想環境は間違いなく起動しているでしょうか? ・仮想環境のCentOSにはWindows側のターミナルソフトからアクセスできていますか、できるならその際の接続先IPアドレスは? Vagrant環境を構成した際の詳細な手順やVagrantfileの内容は? 等々MySQLが走っているCentOSの実行環境についての情報を可能な限りご提示ください。特に「IPアドレスでも試してみた」の内容が「Windows PCのIPアドレス」で試したのか、「Vagrantの仮想環境に割り当てたprivate IPアドレス」で試したのか、がはっきりしないと、その後の流れが大きく変わってきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。再度編集致しました。IPアドレスですが、Vagrantの仮想環境に割り当てたprivate IPアドレスで試しました。

Comment: CentOSの中ではMySQLが動いている状態のようですが、まだまだ環境についてご報告いただかないと、確実なことは何も言えません。・Vagrantの設定でポート番号3306に対するポートフォワーディングは設定しましたか? CentOS側のfirewall設定でポート3306は外部からの通信を受け付けるように設定されていますか? MySQLの設定では外部からの接続を受けつけるようになっていますか? MySQLには外部から接続できるようなユーザ設定を行いましたか?